# #!/bin/bash - no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, executable, shebang

I've created a bash script but when I try to execute it, I get

```
#!/bin/bash no such file or directory
```

I need to run the command: `bash script.sh` for it to work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have this issue now under cygwin with a script I could swear was already running without problems. I checked all answers, but none seems to fit. Other questions and answers also mentioned 32/64 bit issues, but for shell scripts this could be excluded, right?

Comment: Found the reason, added details in new anwer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450389/62636 in case somebody has also used `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash` and also looking here...

Answer (score 152, accepted):

This kind of message is usually due to a buggy shebang line, either an extra carriage return at the end of the first line or a BOM at the beginning of it.

Run:

```
$ head -1 yourscript | od -c
```

and see how it ends.

This is wrong:

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \r  \n
```

This is wrong too:

```
0000000 357 273 277   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n
```

This is correct:

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n
```

Use `dos2unix` (or `sed`, `tr`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`…) to fix your script if this is the issue.

Here is one that will remove both of a BOM and tailing CRs:

```
sed -i '1s/^.*#//;s/\r$//' brokenScript
```

---

Note that the shell you are using to run the script will slightly affect the error messages that are displayed.

Here are three scripts just showing their name (`echo $0`) and having the following respective shebang lines:

correctScript:

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n
```

scriptWithBom:

```
0000000 357 273 277   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n
```

scriptWithCRLF:

```
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \r  \n
```

Under bash, running them will show these messages:

```
$ ./correctScript
./correctScript
$ ./scriptWithCRLF
bash: ./scriptWithCRLF: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
$ ./scriptWithBom
./scriptWithBom: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
./scriptWithBom
```

Running the buggy ones by explicitely calling the interpreter allows the CRLF script to run without any issue:

```
$ bash ./scriptWithCRLF
./scriptWithCRLF
$ bash ./scriptWithBom
./scriptWithBom: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
./scriptWithBom
```

Here is the behavior observed under `ksh`:

```
$ ./scriptWithCRLF
ksh: ./scriptWithCRLF: not found [No such file or directory]
$ ./scriptWithBom
./scriptWithBom[1]: #!/bin/bash: not found [No such file or directory]
./scriptWithBom
```

and under `dash`:

```
$ ./scriptWithCRLF
dash: 2: ./scriptWithCRLF: not found
$ ./scriptWithBom
./scriptWithBom: 1: ./scriptWithBom: #!/bin/bash: not found
./scriptWithBom
```

Comment: Another way of revealing if this is the problem is `hexdump -C yourscript | head -n 1`. I would still use `dos2unix yourscript` to fix it.

Comment: Yes it could very well be that. I edited in on windows. Things for the tip.

Comment: If it were a CRLF problem, you wouldn't see a `#!/bin/bash no such file or directory` error message, as there's no reason anything would try to execute or open `#!/bin/bash`. It's `/bin/bash<CR>` what would be executed.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas As dos2unix fixed the problem, there is little doubt it wasn't a CRLF problem. The error message was probably just inaccurately transcripted..

Comment: `dos2unix` also removes an UTF-8 BOM. A UTF-8 BOM could have explained the error message.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I agree the error message would have included the shebang but the OP complains that the script was not executed when called as is, but correctly run when passed as a bash argument. With an UTF-8 BOM, the script would have been executed in both cases, not just the second one, and the error message would have been displayed in both cases too, which isn't what the OP is describing.

Comment: It is sad how incompatible Microsoft is. Even with something as basic as ASCII.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes. Note that Mac OS used to be ending its lines with a third alternative but is now aligned with Unix/Linux. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411811/why-does-linux-use-lf-as-the-newline-character/411830#411830

Comment: @jlliagre I was commenting about adding a BOM, to the start of the file (it is not even part of UTF-8, and they add it to the start of an ASCII file as well). However you are correct, they do line endings differently as well, making their text files 2%→5% bigger, and incompatible.

Comment: @jlliagre On current macOS a BOM will screw everything up.

Comment: @Clearer On older too. AFAIK a BOM screws everything up whatever the OS.

Answer (score 22):

This can also be caused by a BOM in a UTF-8 script.  If you create the script in Windows sometimes you get some junk at the start of the file.

Comment: BOM can be removed easily using awk, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark

Comment: Note that Visual Studio for Mac will insert a BOM.

Answer (score 13):

Actualy, the right shebang for bash script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Because, in freeBSD, bash is located in `/usr/local/bin/bash`

Comment: "right" is a difficult word to use in such cases. Perhaps a better phrase would be "less error-prone".

Comment: This is terrible too; the assumption that /usr exists is a bad one IMO. Haiku, for instance, does not have /usr.

Comment: @jessicah: `/usr` (as well as `/usr/bin/env`) are *mandatory* paths in a POSIX system, be it Linux, FreeBSD or even MacOS. Haiku is not a *nix system, is a cloud computing platform, so you cannot assume _any_ path or tool.

Comment: Great... This worked for me in CentOS 7

Answer (score 11):

You can use vi to fix both problems if they exist:

```
vi <your_file>
:set ff=unix
:set nobomb
:wq
```

Comment: Answers should be self-contained as much as possible.  The question doesn’t mention two problems; if you’re going to build on other answers, you should *at least* say what they are.  Better yet, you should explain *how* this answers the question.

Comment: Very quick fix without downloading more windows tools, thanks!

Comment: @G-Man Other answers already mention this in much better detail than I wish to go into.  No need to repeat, but if it's not painfully obvious, you can have a WIndows line ending and a hidden Windows BOM character.  I think a lot of people that are scanning answers appreciate brevity instead of being self contained, especially when there is much more detail in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have dos2unix this is a way to fix this issue.

```
cp script _p4 && tr -d '\r' < _p4 > script && rm _p4
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Byte-order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

This could be caused by a BOM. From Wikipedia, a BOM is a

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character, U+FEFF byte order mark (BOM), whose appearance as a magic number at the start of a text stream can signal several things to a program consuming the text

Unfortunately, [it doesn't signal anything to the Linux kernel that handles the she-bang line.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Magic_number) You can verify you have a BOM by using `file`,

```
file /tmp/foo 
/tmp/foo: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Or you can hexdump the first few characters and see [if they match any of the BOM characters manually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding)

You can strip the BOM characters once you know them like this,

```
sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.txt
```

Comment: Works great!  And I can confirm that you **only need to remove the BOM once*.  After I removed it, I could continue to edit the file in Visual Studio and the BOM did not reappear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue by accidentally adding a wrong bash executable to the `PATH` and because in my script the more flexible `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang was used (take first bash executable from path).

```
command -v bash
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/bin//bash
```

I have installed GIT for Windows to work in `cygwin` together with Windows GIT GUIs (was not working with cygwin native git...). I solved this now by switching to `#!/bin/bash` sheband and removing GIT for windows from `PATH`.

Answer (score -3):

Try `#!/bin/bash`

Second thing: `find / -name bash`
Third thing: `ls -al /bin/bash`

Comment: Or just `which bash`.  We know it's finding one  because it's working with `bash script.sh`.

Comment: True. And as mentioned, there is the much more portable /usr/bin/env method to have a program locate bash (or an other interpreter) for you. No need to hardcode a pah.