# How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?

Tags: command-line, files, unicode

I have a file in UTF-8 encoding with BOM and want to remove the BOM. Are there any linux command-line tools to remove the BOM from the file?

```
$ file test.xml
test.xml:  XML 1.0 document, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines
```

Comment: Similar: [AWK with BOM: Is there any cool way to handle Unicode BOM with regexp?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/338836)

Comment: I've made a farily simple tool to do just that a few months ago: https://oskog97.com/read/?path=/small-scripts/killbom&referer=/small-scripts/&title=Small+scripts Might be worth installing something like it in /usr/local/bin if you have many UTF-8 encoded files with BOMs.

Comment: Weirdly, cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240387/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file

Comment: In UTF8, U+FEFF is encoded as 3 bytes: `EF BB BF`, one thing you could do is combine `xxd` and `xxd -r` to change those first three bytes to something within printable ascii range, like `41 41 41`, so that "AAA" will appear in the BOM's place, which you can then simply delete and save with a regular text editor. Bit of a roundabout way but it works.

Comment: `xxd -p` and `xxd -p -r` handily allow removal (or addition) of characters in the hex dump.  On my system, however, I did then have to reformat to use `xxd -p` standard line lengths for all but the last line in order to get `xxd -p -r` to work properly, so this made the process much less handy.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

If you're not sure if the file contains a UTF-8 BOM, then this (assuming the GNU implementation of `sed`) will remove the BOM if it exists, or make no changes if it doesn't.

```
sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < orig.txt > new.txt
```

You can also overwrite the existing file with the `-i` option:

```
sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' orig.txt
```

If you are using the BSD version of `sed` (eg macOS) then you need to have bash do the escaping:

```
 sed $'1s/\xef\xbb\xbf//' < orig.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: this may not work in a utf8 locale, but prepending a locale override to c or posix will always work.

Comment: @hildred I've tested it with the `en_US.UTF-8` locale and it worked. When will it fail?

Comment: @m13r, It depends on the version of sed and compile options. In the failure case a very new version of sed with Unicode character classes will bring the three byte sequence in as a single character which does not match the three character sequence. However in such case you can do a sixteen bit character match. However this is a new feature and not universally present. If you want to test I recommend compiling the latest version.

Comment: To fix it to work with a unicode-enabled sed do LC_ALL=C sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//'

Comment: @CSM nice, but for one special case it does not work: Bevore: `-<U+FEFF>\chapter{xxx}`
After: `+\chapter{xxx}^M`   Explanation: Using MS-word for typos in latex-file. Latex under Linux is showing errors mentioned. Output is from a git system. How could I alter the expression to catch this special case too?

Comment: @CSM, the second command `sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' orig.txt` fails for me but `sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' < orig.txt > orig.txt` works.. I am in `en_US.UTF-8` locale.. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually no worries.. it was for a different reason. Just thought I would leave this here.. that when you redirect a file using `>` it doesn't necessary  write exactly the bits in the original file. This was the reason why the 2 methods were different for me. There were some invalid `utf-8` characters which were being removed when I didn't use the `in-place` change option.

Comment: Does the `1` in `1s/` only run it once?

Comment: @mazunki, `1s/` means only search the first line; other lines are unaffected. The `^` means only match at the start of the (first) line. `\xEF\xBB\xBF` is the UTF-8 BOM (escaped hex string). `//` means replace with nothing. I could have added `1` to the end (for `1s/^xEF\xBB\xBF//1`), which would mean only match the first occurrence of the pattern on the line. But as the the search is anchored with `^`, this won't make any difference.  If the file doesn't have the BOM at the start of the first line, the pattern won't match, and thus no change is made.

Comment: In my case I had multiple occurrences of BOM in same string .. so I used this command: `sed -i 's/\xEF\xBB\xBF//g' orig.txt`

Comment: I joined the Unix community so that I could like this answer! This problem was driving me nuts. Thank you!

Answer (score 129):

A BOM doesn't make sense in UTF-8. Those are generally added by mistake by bogus software on Microsoft OSes.

`dos2unix` will remove it and also take care of other idiosyncrasies of Windows text files.

```
dos2unix test.xml
```

Comment: I agree that a UTF-8 encoded BOM does not make sense, but believe it or not, there are lots of people who think it is a great idea that helps differentiate UTF-8 from other 8-bit encodings. So it is a matter of taste. Windows Notepad adds a BOM on purpose.

Comment: What does it matter if it makes sense or not, when the context is just a question on how to remove it? According to Wikipedia, Notepad requires the BOM to recognize a file as UTF-8, and Google Docs also adds it while exporting a file as text. I doubt they all do it by _mistake_.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62721/discussion-on-answer-by-stephane-chazelas-how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8).

Comment: Is there a way of not converting the line endings and just remove the BOM with `dos2unix`?

Comment: @m13r It should be easier with `unix2dos -r <olddos.txt >nobomdos.txt`

Comment: @Arrow My version of `dos2unix`  does not have the option `-r`. I am using version 6.0.4 (2013-12-30).

Comment: @m13r Then use the [sed script in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381263/232326). That will remove only the bom (if it exist), nothing else will be changed.

Comment: @JohanMyréen there are people who think it is a great idea to draw red line with blue crayon, but it doesn't change the fact that a line drawn with a blue crayon is blue, even if you call it red.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo There are people (like me!) who think it's a great idea not to clutter text files with metadata like UTF-8 encoded BOMs, but that doesn't change the fact that files like this do exist and you will occasionally need to deal with them.

Comment: @JohanMyréen yes, but it is not correct calling them UTF-8. They are not UTF-8 files. They are UTF-8-with-BOM files, which is another file format. I suppose those Windows freaks won't be happy getting ODT files callled MSOffice files :)

Comment: Re: _`"A BOM doesn't make sense in UTF-8"`_, at least in Persian language it make sense, since without BOM they don't appear as Persian as I'm always adding BOM bytes to the beginning of a Persian context file in *nix env to be able to correctly shown its Persian content in Windows env like excel or notepad, etc.

Comment: You can now use `fromdos`

Comment: HTTP and other Internet standards are clearly wrong, they use CRLF line endings, which is "a Microsoft idiosyncrasy" ... really? This is *really* getting old. There are many many MANY valid criticisms of Microsoft's business practices or Windows, but this ain't one ...

Answer (score 96):

#### Using VIM

1. Open file in VIM:

   ```
    vi text.xml
   ```
2. Remove BOM encoding:

   ```
    :set nobomb
   ```
3. Save the file and quit:

   ```
    :x
   ```

---

For a non-interactive solution, try the following command line:

```bash
vi -c ":set nobomb" -c ":wq" text.xml
```

That should remove the BOM, save the file and quit, all from the command line.

Comment: Oddly with vim 8 on a mac, I have a csv utf-8 file made by Excel and it starts with `<feff>`, yet `:set nobomb` doesn't modify or remove it.

Comment: This is much faster than `tail` on large files.

Comment: For multiple files: `vim -c ":bufdo set nobomb|update" -c "q" *`

Answer (score 35):

It is possible to remove the BOM from a file with the `tail` command:

```
tail -c +4 withBOM.txt > withoutBOM.txt
```

Be aware that this chops the first 3 bytes (`-c +N` makes the output start at byte nr. `N`, so it cuts the first (N-1) bytes) from the file, so be sure that the file really contains the BOM before running `tail`.

Comment: Why 4? The BOM has 3 byte.

Comment: @deviantfan Which is why you need to start at the 4th byte if you want to skip it.

Comment: `tail` is using 1 based indexing?! WTF!

Comment: @CodesInChaos, `tail -c -1` or `tail -c 1` (what `tail` is generally used for) is the content starting with the last byte, `tail -c +1` starting with the first byte. `tail -c 0`/`tail -c +0` for that would be a lot more unintuitive.

Comment: @deviantfan: `(dd bs=1 count=3 of=/dev/null; cat) <input >output`. Or with GNU `(head -c3 >/dev/null; cat)` -- even in UTF8 or other non-singlebyte locale; GNU head does 'char'=byte.

Comment: It doesnt work in windows using bash

Comment: @david You need the `tail` command for this to work... `bash` has nothing to do with this and only calls the `tail` binary... What error do you get? Maybe have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command
I have tested it with "Git Bash for Windows" and it worked for me..

Comment: This `tail` command works **only** when the file has a 4-bytes BOM, otherwise it's **destructive** as it blindly chops the first 4 characters of the input file regardless of what it contains.

Answer (score 8):

I use a vim one-liner on the regular for this:

```
vim --clean -c 'se nobomb|wq' filename

vim --clean -c 'bufdo se nobomb|wqa' filename1 filename2 ...
```

Comment: This should also be achievable using VIM's `ex` personality.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
LANG=C LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/\r$// ; 1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' -i -- filename
```

to remove the byte order mark from the beginning of the file, if it has any, as well as convert any CR LF newlines to LF only. The `LANG=C LC_ALL=C` tells the shell you want the command to run in the default C locale (also known as the default POSIX locale), where the three bytes forming the Byte Order Mark are treated as bytes. The `-i` option to sed means in-place. If you use `-i.old`, then sed saves the original file as `filename.old`, and the new file (with the modifications, if any) as `filename`.

---

I personally like to have this as `~/bin/fix-ms`; for example, as

```
#!/bin/dash
export LANG=C LC_ALL=C
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    for FILE in "$@" ; do
        sed -e 's/\r$// ; 1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' -i -- "$FILE" || exit 1
    done
else
    exec sed -e 's/\r$// ; 1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//'
fi
```

so that if I need to apply this to say all C source files and headers (my old code from the MS-DOS era, for example!), I just run

```
find . -name '*.[CHch]' -print0 | xargs -r0 ~/bin/ms-fix
```

or, if I just want to look at such a file, without modifying it, I can run

```
~/bin/ms-fix < filename | less
```

and not see the ugly `<U+FEFF>` in my UTF-8 terminal.

Comment: Why not simply `sed -e 's/\r$// ; 1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' -i -- "$@"`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Because I want the script to exit immediately if there is an issue with a replacement, which `sed -e 's/\r$// ; 1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' -i -- "$@"` does not do; it does return an exit code, but it processes all files listed in the argument list before exiting.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The `--` before the file name(s) is, of course, important: without it, file names beginning with a dash may be considered options by sed. I edited those into my answer; thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different problem, and am putting this here for someone who, like me, ends up here with data full of `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` characters (which are known as `Byte Order Mark` when they are the first character of the file).

I got this data by copying out of grafana query metrics field, and it had multiple (17) `\xef\xbb\xbf` sequences (which show up in vim as `rate<feff>(<feff>node<feff>{<feff>job<feff>`) in a single line with only 81 actual characters.

I modified Nominal Animal's code just slightly:

```
LANG=C LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/\xef\xbb\xbf//g'
```

And the `:set nobomb` thing in `vim` only removes the very first one in the file.

tried this:

```
LANG=C vim b
```

Then `vim` doesn't show them, but they are still there (even after a write...)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and ended up writing a dedicated utility `bom(1)` for this. It's [available here](https://github.com/archiecobbs/bom).

Here's the man page:

```
NAME
     bom -- Decode Unicode byte order mark

SYNOPSIS
     bom --strip [--expect types] [--lenient] [--prefer32] [--utf8] [file]
     bom --detect [--expect types] [--prefer32] [file]
     bom --print type
     bom --list
     bom --help
     bom --version

DESCRIPTION
     bom decodes, verifies, reports, and/or strips the byte order mark (BOM) at the
     start of the specified file, if any.

     When no file is specified, or when file is -, read standard input.

OPTIONS
     -d, --detect
             Report the detected BOM type to standard output and then exit.

             See SUPPORTED BOM TYPES for possible values.

     -e, --expect types
             Expect to find one of the specified BOM types, otherwise exit with an
             error.

             Multiple types may be specified, separated by commas.

             Specifying NONE is acceptable and matches when the file has no (sup-
             ported) BOM.

     -h, --help
             Output command line usage help.

     -l, --lenient
             Silently ignore any illegal byte sequences encountered when converting
             the remainder of the file to UTF-8.

             Without this flag, bom will exit immediately with an error if an ille-
             gal byte sequence is encountered.

             This flag has no effect unless the --utf8 flag is given.

     --list  List the supported BOM types and exit.

     -p, --print type
             Output the byte sequence corresponding to the type byte order mark.

     --prefer32
             Used to disambiguate the byte sequence FF FE 00 00, which can be
             either a UTF-32LE BOM or a UTF-16LE BOM followed by a NUL character.

             Without this flag, UTF-16LE is assumed; with this flag, UTF-32LE is
             assumed.

     -s, --strip
             Strip the BOM, if any, from the beginning of the file and output the
             remainder of the file.

     -u, --utf8
             Convert the remainder of the file to UTF-8, assuming the character
             encoding implied by the detected BOM.

             For files with no (supported) BOM, this flag has no effect and the
             remainder of the file is copied unmodified.

             For files with a UTF-8 BOM, the identity transformation is still
             applied, so (for example) illegal byte sequences will be detected.

     -v, --version
             Output program version and exit.

SUPPORTED BOM TYPES
     The supported BOM types are:

     NONE    No supported BOM was detected.

     UTF-7   A UTF-7 BOM was detected.

     UTF-8   A UTF-8 BOM was detected.

     UTF-16BE
             A UTF-16 (Big Endian) BOM was detected.

     UTF-16LE
             A UTF-16 (Little Endian) BOM was detected.

     UTF-32BE
             A UTF-32 (Big Endian) BOM was detected.

     UTF-32LE
             A UTF-32 (Little Endian) BOM was detected.

     GB18030
             A GB18030 (Chinese National Standard) BOM was detected.

EXAMPLES
     To tell what kind of byte order mark a file has:

           $ bom --detect

     To normalize files with byte order marks into UTF-8, and pass other files
     through unchanged:

           $ bom --strip --utf8

     Same as previous example, but discard illegal byte sequences instead of gener-
     ating an error:

           $ bom --strip --utf8 --lenient

     To verify a properly encoded UTF-8 or UTF-16 file with a byte-order-mark and
     output it as UTF-8:

           $ bom --strip --utf8 --expect UTF-8,UTF-16LE,UTF-16BE

     To just remove any byte order mark and get on with your life:

           $ bom --strip file

RETURN VALUES
     bom exits with one of the following values:

     0       Success.

     1       A general error occurred.

     2       The --expect flag was given but the detected BOM did not match.

     3       An illegal byte sequence was detected (and --lenient was not speci-
             fied).

SEE ALSO
     iconv(1)

     bom: Decode Unicode byte order mark, https://github.com/archiecobbs/bom.
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found this tiny command-line tool which adds or removes the BOM  on arbitary UTF-8 encoded files: [UTF BOM Utils](https://code.google.com/p/utf-bom-utils/) ([new link](https://github.com/jlblancoc/utf-bom-utils) at github)

Little drawback, you can download only the plain C++ source code. You have to create the makefile (with [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), for example) and compile it by yourself, binaries are not provided on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but since I had a slightly different issue, I'm posting so others may benefit.

My text file was randomly haunted by characters `\fe\ff`, luckily for me they appeared at start of the lines and the set of allowed characters is limited to alphanumeric.

The below command in `vim` cuts first non-alphanumeric character, but use it with caution as your set of allowed characters might vary.

```
:%s/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by ***Smirk*** was a great hint about how to do this on an VERY OLD UNIX system that has ancient versions of **vim**, **ex**, **iconv**, **piconv**, etc.  I did not want to restrict to treatment of only alpha-numeric as non-BOM characters, so these patterns assume two or three leading non-printable ASCII on the first line only are the BOM characters to remove.  A non-interactive method was also desired.

An *excommands* file was created as follows:

```
" UTF-8 Byte-Order-Mark (BOM) characters
1,1g/^[^ -~][^ -~][^ -~][ -~]/s/^...//
" UTF-16LE, UTF-16 (Big Endian) BOM
" ex happens to strip unwanted NULs
1,1g/^[^ -~][^ -~][ -~]/s/^..//
```

To remove the BOM characters:

```
ex - file-w-BOM <excommands
```

To use interactively, just enter as a colon command in **vim**.  For example:

```
:1,1g/^[^ -~][^ -~][^ -~][ -~]/s/^...//
```

NOTE:  For some reason, the **ex** on my VERY OLD UNIX system just happened to remove the unwanted *NUL* bytes from UTF-16LE files in a way that didn't garble data that all cleanly corresponded with ASCII characters.  This was fortunate since both **iconv** and **piconv** on the VERY OLD UNIX system were also unable to properly re-encode UTF-16LE as something else.

CAVEAT:  The above is sure to BREAK files that contain multi-byte characters that do not map to plain ASCII, so the solution must only be used with this in mind.