# Is this some byte order mark problem

Tags: text-formatting, file-format

My question seems to come from differences between text files in different OSes. So I will try my luck here.

I would like to try the default project created from [a .NET Core template](https://github.com/JasonGT/CleanArchitecture)  on Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed SQL Server `mssql-server_15.0.4003.23-3_amd64.deb` and choose Express as edition. Since LocalDB is Windows only, I figure that I have to modify `src/WebUI/appsettings.json` to replace LocalDB connection string with the following SQL Server connection string (I am not sure if it is correct):

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=ExampleDb;User Id=sa;Password=password;"
  },
```

Then I go into `src/WebUI/` and build it but fail (see below). The errors seem not related to my change of the connection string.

Regarding the first error, I open `src/Domain/Domain.csproj` in Emacs, which shows something strange `<U+FEFF>`, which https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark says is about endianness. I wonder how I could make the files work?

```
<U+FEFF>namespace default.Domain.Enums
{
    public enum PriorityLevel
    {
        None,
        Low,
        Medium,
        High
    }
}
```

Thanks.

```
$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 147.56 ms for /tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj.
  Restore completed in 213.91 ms for /tmp/test/default/src/Application/Application.csproj.
  Restore completed in 57.04 ms for /tmp/test/default/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj.
  Restore completed in 9.65 ms for /tmp/test/default/src/WebUI/WebUI.csproj.
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(2,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(4,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,28): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,32): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(7,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(5,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,28): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,27): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(6,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,28): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(5,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(4,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(1,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Enums/PriorityLevel.cs(2,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(3,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Exceptions/AdAccountInvalidException.cs(4,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(1,28): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(2,32): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(6,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
ValueObjects/AdAccount.cs(7,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(4,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/ValueObject.cs(5,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(1,28): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(2,27): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(5,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoItem.cs(6,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,7): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,7): error CS1002: ; expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,22): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(1,28): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(4,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Entities/TodoList.cs(5,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,11): error CS1001: Identifier expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,26): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,11): error CS1514: { expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(3,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
Common/AuditableEntity.cs(4,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/tmp/test/default/src/Domain/Domain.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    60 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion byte order marks are a bit of a mess and generally unnecessary in modern computing.  Their original use was for UTF-16 and UTF-32 which, for interchang between computers of different architecture, needed a way to differentiate between [little-endian and big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  UTF-16 and UTF-32 are much less favoured than UTF-8 these days and utf-8 doesn't *need* a BOM.

The standard on when to use a BOM is annoyingly vague:

See page 67 here: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/UnicodeStandard-12.0.pdf

> Data streams (or files) that begin with the U+FEFF byte order mark are likely to contain
>   Unicode characters. It is recommended that applications sending or receiving untyped
>   data streams of coded characters use this signature. If other signaling methods are used,
>   signatures should not be employed.

As a general rule, most data streams are typed.  For example utf-8 configuration files are *expected* to be utf-8 and so by definition are not "untyped".  Thus as a general rule BOM should not be included unless you know otherwise.

You are more likely to cause problems by adding a BOM than removing one. 
 [UTF-8 was designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  This allows you to use UTF-8 in a lot of places that were only expecting ASCII.  But the BOM is not part of and not ASCII and many / most programs reading text files do not handle it well.  Most don't know to ignore it at the start of a file, or strip it when concatenating files.  Programs that expect a BOM are usually tolerant to its absence.

However many text editors will add a BOM without telling you.  You may have inadvertently added it when you edited the configuration file.

There's another question directly asking how to remove a BOM:
[How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file)

I would remove any BOM added to your configuration files. It is highly unlikely MS SQL is expecting them.

Answer (score 2):

Mayhap somthing like

```
iconv -fUTF16 -tUTF8 file
```