# bash script "No such file..."

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to run a back script that I wrote that I have placed in the /srv directory on my xubuntu machine.

But when I try to run it, it errors with the following...

```
user@linuxbox:/srv$ sudo ./backup.sh 
sudo: unable to execute ./backup.sh: No such file or directory
```

The contents of my backup.sh script are as follows...

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync --update -raz --progress ./git  '/media/user/New Volume/BACKUP'
```

EDIT: I did flip the executable bit using chmod.

Here is the permissions...

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 81 Mar 18 17:16 /srv/backup.sh
```

EDIT: Apparently another running instance of nano is editing my file. But I did a restart of the PC, so not sure how that persisted. Could this be the problem? This happens when I try to edit in nano.

```
File backup.sh is being edited (by root with nano 2.5.3, PID 14039); continue?
```

When I try to kill that process by the PID, it says "No such process"

Comment: Executable bit is missing.

Comment: ...and that there are no non-printable characters in the filename? Trailing space, maybe?

Comment: Please show us the output of `ls -l /srv/backup.sh` (just so we can have it right the in the question and confirm the obvious: that the file is there and executable).

Comment: Also `ls -l /bin/sh`

Comment: `head -n 1 backup.sh|od -t x1` and look for `0d`

Comment: You’re not getting any good answers because, from what you’re saying, you’re doing everything right. The results you’re describing don’t make sense. So I’m throwing out a random lifeline in the hope of getting some information that might shed some light on this: Try running your script, both with **`./`** and with a full path, *both with and without*  `sudo`, and post the results. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to include all relevant information.  (P.S. The fact that nano believes that another running instance of it is editing the file should not make any difference.)

Comment: And, if that doesn’t resolve it, do `cat -A backup.sh`.  (The first two or three lines of output should be enough to clarify some issues.)

Comment: @G-Man "No such file or directory" when running scripts on UNIX is typical for scripts with Windows newlines.  FWIW.

Comment: missing executable bit should give "Permission denied" instead of "No such file or directory"

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Well, depending on what shell you're running. Bash manages to give better diagnostics.

Comment: `sudo` doesn't use a shell.

Comment: @MichaelHomer `sudo` indeed doesn't use a shell.  Actually running the script does though.

Comment: @G-Man It isn't the shell that complains, it's the kernel.  Namely, it parses the shebang line, and tries to run `bash\r`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: As I said, it depends.  Running bash 4.1 and 4.3, if I create `foo` with `#!/bar/gain`, do `chmod +x foo`, and run `./foo`, I get `bash: ./foo: /bar/gain: bad interpreter`.  Frankly, I’m not sure how it does that, inasmuch as I believe that I understand how shebangs work, and bash *should* just be getting `ENOENT` for `./foo`, and it shouldn’t even see the `/bar/gain`, and yet somehow it does.  Sorry, but I don’t feel like running `strace` on it right now.

Comment: @G-Man Hmm.  It looks like `bash` tries to optimize running scripts and parses the shebang line itself.

Comment: Meanwhile, we’re still waiting for the OP to provide results from `od` and/or `cat -A`.  I give up; I’m voting to close.

Comment: FYI: This is almost always a case of an extra carriage return (CR) getting in the file, or it being in Windows/DOS CRLF format instead of Unix linefeed (LF)-only format. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27054/bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is use the full path instead of relative, and check to make sure you have "execute" bit set. If you can't do an `ls /srv/backup.sh` then you know it's a name/path issue. Likewise if no execute bit set, even root will not be able to execute it.

i.e. `sudo /srv/backup.sh`

Comment: when I did ls command it listed backup.sh in green. Does that mean the execute bit is set correctly?

Comment: Per Jeff and Terdon's request, to verify do a long listing `ls -l /srv/backup.sh` so we can see the full permissions.
If you don't see an "x" listed in the permissions then that would be a no.

Comment: I updated with new info.