# /usr/bin/env python runs on cmdline, fails in #! line

Tags: shell-script, python, environment-variables, shebang

I'm trying to make a python script runnable, by adding the following "shebang" first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

but when I run the file, I get:

```
$ myscript.py
: No such file or directory
```

Now, if I just try the `env` line directly, it works:

```
]$ /usr/bin/env python
Python 2.6 (r26:66714, May  5 2010, 14:02:39)
etc. etc.
```

Why is the same line failing inside the file, but succeeding outside of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#!/bin/bash - no such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27054/bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @UncleBilly: Not quite, because that's a different error message. But - it's the same answer. So, up to you whether to mark this a dupe.

Comment: The benefit of duplicates is that they are multiple signposts, each with their own wording & variation, that point to the same underlying issue. I would consider this a duplicate as it's the same underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an invalid character somewhere in your shebang line. Since you're the one who inserted it, it's likely a carriage-return, i.e. your line ends with a newline and a carriage return (or vice-versa) - in the ODS style of line breaking.

Try using `dos2unix` on your script file to convert all the line breaks to only be `0x10` (UNIX-style).