# a simple case/esac construct exercise fails, why?

Tags: bash, case

This is the BASH script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Type in a color name, please: " COLOR

case "$COLOR" in
    green | red | yellow)
    echo -n "nice colors!"
    ;;
    *)
    echo -n "meh..."
    ;;
esac
```

Once set the `x` permission to the script for user, I run it but get the following:

```
[inewton@centos7 LPIC1-exercises]$ ./colors.sh
Type in a color name, please: pink
./colors.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'/colors.sh: line 12: `esac
[inewton@centos7 LPIC1-exercises]$
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> '/colors.sh: line 12: `esac
> ```

Notice the weird placement of the closing quote at the beginning of the line. That's a sign that there was a [carriage return (CR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character after the word `esac`. Bash treats the CR as part of the word `esac␍`, so this is not a reserved word, and the actual word `esac` is missing.

CR characters are part of Windows line endings: a Unix line ending is the LF (line feed) character alone, whereas a Windows line ending is the two-character sequence CR+LF. See [#!/bin/bash - no such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27054/bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory) for more explanations. The twist here is that your file has mixed line endings: previous lines didn't cause a problem so at least some of them must have Unix line endings.

Remove all carriage returns from your file. Most editors will show them explicitly in a file with mixed line endings.

Comment: There is probably a carriage return on that last line only.

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed, although the `echo` lines could have a CR, and other lines could have a space and a CR with the space getting lost in the copying.

Comment: It could be so, yes. It seems as if `dos2unix` handles files that have a mix of DOS and Unix line-endings.